# Bootstrap Popover data-content readable for Google

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, seo, popover

How can I make the data-content of a bootstrap popover be readable for google? My Code:

```
<li data-original-title="" class="tag-popover" title="" 
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" 
data-content="Data-Content-Text.">
Responsive Webdesign</li>
```

I have some more tags that need a short description by a popover. So I need a solution for several popover-contents.

---

First Idea: Is it possible to just add a span with the class sr-only or is this "spam" or even not visible for google:

```
<li> data-original-title="" [...]
Responsive Webdesign <span class="sr-only">Data-Content-Text.</span></li>
```

---

Second Idea:
**Is it possible to open every popover by visiting the website for two seconds and close it after this two seconds?** Would Google read the popover-content that is build by javascript then?

Answer (score 1):

For your last question, Google can't read JS or any redirection through it.

Any data you want Google to index it, it must be visible for the user first, you have to treat Google like any regular user.

You need to change in your structure in order to crawl and index them.

Any hidden text will be a threat on your website, be careful.